# Creating a meshgrid for a function with comparisons

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to plot a surface plot for the following function.

```
def G(X):
    if X[0]<X[1]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

For that I'm using the following code

```
import numpy as np
x_values=np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y_values=np.linspace(-5,+5,100)
F_values=G(np.meshgrid(x_values,y_values))

import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go


trace=go.Surface(x=x_values,y=y_values,z=F_values)
data=[trace]
fig=go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
np.meshgrid(x_values,y_values)
```

And this gives me the error:
*The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

Upon doing some search I realized that the problem was about having a comparison in the function `G` and to synchronize with the meshgrid. (Some thing like [this](https://sopython.com/canon/119/the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous/) )

But I  don't know how to fix that.
I really appreciate your help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is you desired output but in my opinion you should keep it simple:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def G(X,Y):
    r = [[]]
    for i in range(0,len(X)):
        r.append([])
        for j in range(0, len(Y)):
            if X[i] < Y[j]:
                r[i].append(1)
            else:
                r[i].append(2)
    return r


x_values=np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y_values=np.linspace(-5,+5,100)
F_values=G(x_values,y_values)


trace=go.Surface(x=x_values,y=y_values,z=F_values)
data=[trace]
fig=go.Figure(data=data)
fig.show()
```

[image]